# How to theme simplenews unsubscribe page?

Tags: 6, theming, emails

I'am trying to theme Unsubscribe Page for my Newsletter to much the Newsletter Design.
Does anyone know how to theme unsubscribe page in Drupal 6:

example.com/newsletter/confirm/remove/*

Comment: Did you see special class on this page using Firebug which you can use to theme it?

Comment: Aha, Yes I can see ".page-newsletter". That's one way thanks. But is there any way to use Template Suggestion?

Comment: Download Themer module along with Devel and it will show the theme files you can create. Which content type is it? You can easily theme each content type or even a specific node.

Comment: @IvailoMilenkov: Please write down your findings as an answer, so that others who might be looking for this information can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer this just so that people that are looking for the answer will see it.

As @AgA said:

You can install the [Themer Module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer), you will require the [Devel Module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer).
Enable these modules and go to the path that you would like to theme.

The Themer module will give you suggested naming conventions that you can use to override that page's theme.

In your case it was the content type newsletter, coming to the suggested name of page-newsletter.tpl.php but there will be more suggestions which you can use to override an already overridden more general tpl.